# How to ignore Tags from XML if the tag is missing in JAXB, while parsing in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

Hi I have two xml almost same but one has some extra tag, I don't want to create a separate class for both of them, instead ignore or null the element in the class if its missing.

```
1st XML example is 

<Image>
  <Name> Image01.jpg </Name>
</Image>

2nd XML example is 

<Image>
  <Name> Image01.jpg </Name>
  <Path> C:/Image01.jpg </Path>
</Image>

public class Image{
   String name;
   String path;

}
```

If I parse the XML 1 it should not ignore the Path element. and if I load the XML 2 it should not ignore the Path element.

Comment: `Path` is eventually `null`able, so plan for that. Like any other nullable attribute(s), if it's there, you would get the value from it...if not, well, you just "ignore" it.

Comment: What happens if you try to unmarshall 1st XML as `Image` with `path?

Comment: Have you tried `@XmlElement(required=false) String path;`?

Comment: @devpuh required is false by default so he needs not to do anything

Comment: @Aqeel-haider by default your null values will be ignored. Just tgag the name, and path with @XmlElement and tag image with `@XmlRootElement()` and  `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Comment: Found the solution I have to add @XMLElement(nillable = true). Thanks a lot